# Link in picture gallery not working

Tags: picture-library

I'm fairly new in sharepoint so i hope you can help me.

```
<table width="682" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f9f9f9" style="margin-bottom:7px;">
  <tr>
    <td width="201" rowspan="3" valign="top"><a href="{@link}">
    <img border="0" style="width:201px; height:112px; overflow:hidden;" src="{@FileRef}"/></a></td>
    <td width="12" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td width="415"></td>
    <td width="13" rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="{@URL}">
        <p><strong><xsl:value-of select="@Title"></xsl:value-of></strong></p></a>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="@Description"></xsl:value-of></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I created a new column in the picture library called "URL" which basically stores a list of URL corresponding to the image when clicked. However when I tried it, it just won't work. below is the code that I used

This basically shows an image, a title and a description. I was able to show all but when I clicked on the link, it just reloads the page. It would be awesome if you can help me with this.

thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this will work but worth a try:

in href try adding "http://"

also if firefox or ie open up developer tools to inspect the elements (image) to see what the url is for that image :)

im presuming that your pulling the url from an xml file?

```
<a href="{@URL}">
```

also i noticed that you have the link stored within sharepoint not xml lol, im getting confused :( , how are you storing the url? is it plain text or actual url? in your case it should be plain text as the others that you have done so sucessfully! url will be somthing like this `(http://test.com,test)` as you can see its not what you require! as its injected straigt to html it should only be the url text

Comment: am actually pulling the URL from the URL column which i created in the picture library. Then I called those URL values via XSLT. When I opened the developers tool in IE, i saw that the link is just referencing to its parent page or the #